# Scheduling - Context switch with one or more kernel stack per process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, context-switch

Considering the Linux case, where we have a kernel stack for each user stack, from what I know, whenever a context switch happens, we switch to kernel mode of the current process.

Here we save the current status, registers, program data etc. of the current process and then the scheduler (not sure if it runs in this kernel) saves the PCB and loads the PCB of the next process to be scheduled.

Now the first question is if the explanation above seems to make sense for you, considering a context switch where each process has also a "dedicated" kernel stack.

And the other part of my question is, how would a context switch happen if we had a single kernel stack for all the processes?

Answer (score 0):

**Each process has its own kernel stack.**

I will use the latest kernel as an example.

In `include/linux/sched.h`, there is a union named [`thread_union`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/510c8a899caf095cb13d09d203573deef15db2fe/include/linux/sched.h#L1414) and its definition is as follows:

```
union thread_union {
#ifndef CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK
    struct thread_info thread_info;
#endif
    unsigned long stack[THREAD_SIZE/sizeof(long)];
};
```

When a new process is created, the kernel will allocate a `thread_union` to it and each process will have its "dedicated" `thread_union`.

1. The first member `thread_info` is a struct which contains a pointer to the `task_struct` of this process.
2. The second member `stack` is the kernel stack of this process.
3. This is a union, so the two members use the same memory space. `thread_info` is not very big, so there is enough space for kernel stack.

When a process invokes a system call, it will use its own kernel stack and save the `%ESP` which points to user stack in the kernel stack.

Each process has its own `thread_union`, so they have their own "dedicated" kernel stack.

Comment: So this answer is regarding the first part of my question right? Because from here I still cannot understand quite well how a context switch would work in a case where all processes (with their respective user stack) are based on a single (UNIQUE) kernel stack

Comment: @DevX10 Each process has its own `thread_union`, so they have their own "dedicated" kernel stack which is a member of `thread_union`. The pointer to kernel stack is `ss0:esp0` which is saved in TSS. When a context switch happens, TSS will be changed, so the kernel stack will also be switched.

Comment: Yes but the question is how WOULD it work in the other case? I'm not talking about linux (my example was to show this kind of system where we have a "dedicated" kernel stack for each process, but there are also systems where we only have ONE kernel stack).
And the question is how would something like this work? Where would we save the registers, the program data, the user stack pointer for each process when switching?

Comment: @DevX10 Sorry, I only know some knowledge about Linux. I think it is impossible that all process use the same kernel stack because the data will be corrupted.